# Remap mode to the new tree sitter mode not working

Tags: major-mode

I"m trying to use the following code to remap `js-mode` to `js-ts-mode`.

```lisp
(add-to-list 'major-mode-remap-alist '(js-mode . js-ts-mode))
```

(Edit)
I am using default emacs with a custom init file (only a few changes so far) I am expecting that `major-mode-remap-alist` will remap with the form `(MODE . FUNCTION)` as I want to be using the new tree-sitter mode for javascript.

Comment: Welcome to emacs.SE! I gather you are using emacs 29.1. Please tell us what you expect to have happen and what is actually happening. In addition, if you are using any particular emacs distribution (doom, spacemacs, etc.) please also mention that in the question, thanks!

Comment: @Trevoke I have gone ahead and added some more context

Comment: Did you try to manually run `M-x js-ts-mode RET`, i.e. are you sure you have everything needed for treesitter installed?

Comment: yes running the command `js-ts-mode` works as expected. The problem is I open a `.js` and the major-mode is still on `js-mode` instead of `js-ts-mode`

Comment: try to use `javascript-mode` instead of `js-mode` (worked for me)

Comment: That worked thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking help topic for the `major-mode-remap-alist`, there is a link to `auto-mode-alist` that defines major modes to be applied initially:

```
Alist mapping file-specified mode to actual mode.
Every entry is of the form (MODE . FUNCTION) which means that in order
to activate the major mode MODE (specified via something like
‘auto-mode-alist’, file-local variables, ...) we should actually call
FUNCTION instead.
```

Following `auto-mode-alist` we can find out that `*.js` files are actually `javascript-mode` not `js-mode` (which are aliased to each other but, still):

```
...
 ("\\.js[mx]?\\'" . javascript-mode)
 ("\\.har\\'" . javascript-mode)
...
```

Thus instead of

```
(add-to-list 'major-mode-remap-alist '(js-mode . js-ts-mode))
```

you should use:

```
(add-to-list 'major-mode-remap-alist '(javascript-mode . js-ts-mode))
```

Comment: ⁺¹ judging by the `auto-mode-alist` it also seems that if you lack `foo-mode`, then remapping it to a `foo-ts-mode` does nothing. Apparently you have to map `foo-ts-mode` to a file with extension `.foo` manually :c

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION

> try to use javascript-mode instead of js-mode (worked for me) –
> Maxim Kim